# <option> disabled выпадает из serializeArray(). Я в тупике

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Классический пример

```
<select name="auto" disabled>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Если мы будем передавать эту форму через ajax и сборку в массив через serializeArray(), то этот SELECT не передается.

Если параметр "disabled" убрать - то передается.

Как решить головоломку, если на этом SELECT мне нужно оставить параметр disabled?

Пример кода подтверждает: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=5ajiUJiogj

Comment: покажи свой js. в select до disabled значение выбирается?

Comment: $.ajax({ type: $form.attr('method'), url: $form.attr('action'), dataType: 'json', data: $form.serializeArray(), success: function(data) { console.log(data); } });

Comment: Все как обычно, сборка формы по #id методом serializeArray().

Comment: Например, перед отправкой снимайте флаг `disabled` (`elem.removeAttr('disabled')`). По завершению отправки вешайте обратно. (`elem.attr('disabled','disabled');`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284464/submit-disabled-fields

Comment: Всё же не работает сериалайз при дисейбл: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=5ajiUJiogj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ds =  $('#id').find('select:disabled'); // Список отключенных select этой формы
ds.prop('disabled', false); // Включаем все
var data =  $('#id').serializeArray(); // Готовим данные для отправки
ds.prop('disabled', true); // Отключаем те, которые были отключены
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге решение складывается из двух вариантов:

1. Снимать disabled перед отправкой и ставить обратно
2. Создать копию этого поля с атрибутом hidden и записывать туда результаты.